# What should I use to share data with two computers in python?

Tags: python, database

Hypothetically I've made a GUI application in Python, and it stores all of it's data to a file.txt, and displays it when run next time. Now I want to share between two computers (ex. make file.txt of computer1 be visible to file.txt on computer2 and opposite). I suppose I should go with "online" database, but what kind of database should I use? Which one has a good "relationship" with python and generally good in storing stuff I can store in mysql database. And if the answer is MySql, or any other database really, how do I approach getting one online and getting my application to connect to it.
By the way p2p connection is not a good solution because I need to have 2 computers online at the same time to be able to communicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A SQL database will work just fine.

You can use the pyodbc python module to interact with it.

If you need a free SQL database online just google for some free hosting that supports PHP. Usually they also provide a SQL database.

Answer (score 0):

you can also put that `file.txt` on a Samba server or NFS or something similar that is accessible to both computers, just like any SQL based storage